# jQuery fadeIn() on display none

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div where I did a `$('#div').css('display', 'none');`

Now, to bring this item back, I want to fade it in. However, it seems like `$('#div').fadeIn()` is not doing it, but I don't want to set display back to block, as if I do it just re-appears instantly instead of fading.. any ideas?

Comment: Can we see the markup and code you're using?

Comment: pelase give us snippet of your code

Comment: Did `.hide()` really made it work?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try

```
$('#div').hide();
```

to hide the element.

**Update:** I suggested this because I came a problem with setting `.css('display', 'none')` on the `body` in Firefox. But it should work for other elements.

But if it does not work with `hide()` then you definitely have another problem and you have to post more code or provide a demo.

In which browser does it fail? Are you sure `$('#div').fadeIn()` is executed?

Comment: This is not the correct answer and here is why: you can't start the object hidden, except by first hiding it with hide(). I believe this is an actual bug for the folks that need to begin an object hidden via CSS and then present it to the user at a later time

Comment: hey.. just came across a link to this from [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978913/jquery-fadein-method-isnt-working).... and the OPs seems to be agreeing to this as a solution... do you have any further information regarding this behavior... calling `hide()` set the `display` to `none` isn't it

Answer (score 6):

4 years too late but im hoping this will at least help someone out.

You need to first change the CSS class using jquery to `visibility:hidden` and then apply the fade in function. You can chain these within the same function or run them seperately. Either way you should see the element just fade back into existance as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$('#div').hide();
```

instead of

```
display:none;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add speed option;

```
$('#div').fadeIn(1000);
```

It working for me...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem caused by CSS set to the element and its `:hover` state.

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
```

I removed those lines above and finally jquery's `fadeIn()` worked flawlessly.

Also make sure that you do not use `display:none !important;`

And yes, you only need to set CSS `display:none;` and then use `fadeIn()`.