# No display in firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

http://client.henrybuilt.com/login.php

For some reason, nothing is displaying on the page.

Works totally fine in Chrome, but no idea what's going on it Firefox.

Thanks

Comment: Well you should always include a DOCTYPE just in good form, though I do not know if that is the issue.

Comment: Using firebug, it looks like body tag has display:none on it.

Comment: ..and if it worked totally fine with chrome, it was probably an cache issue, try ctrl+shift+R (to force reload browser) and see it again. And to add more: I would use following combo always when you are working with css to be sure to see latest changes. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox throws up this warning

```
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render
with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from
outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must to be declared in the 
document or in the transfer protocol.
```

This may be a cause.

I have attached what the view source code looks like. the `html` tag is highlighted in red pointing out that there is some error.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

Your body tag has the `display:none` property set on it.  Remove that from this block in your `styles/main.css` file:

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#FCFCFC;
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Then use jQuery's `hide()` instead of `display:none`.  See [the answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446176/jquery-fadein-on-display-none) for more details.

Comment: then i would have to wait for the document to load and the user would see the document momentarily before it hid.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this instead of fadeIn..

```
$('body').css('display','block');
```