# jQuery fadeIn() method isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML code (I put the important parts):

```
<div id = "about" style = "display:none;">
<h2>About Us</h2>
<p>Objective: To teach and use skills in relation to creating games.</p>
<p>Where: CAT 145</p>
<p>When: Monday's at 6:30pm</p>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    fadingIn();
};

function fadingIn() {
    //jQuery
    $(function() {
        $('#about').fadeIn('slow'); //fades in the text
    });
}
```

When I do this exact same JavaScript code (I copy and pasted it) on another page it works fine, but for some reason on this page it doesn't work.

Comment: You have an exact answer for this [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446176/jquery-fadein-on-display-none

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NE42S/1/

Comment: any error in your browser console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an exact answer for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446176/jquery-fadein-on-display-none).
Suggested behavior is using hide() and not display:none

Comment: Great. If this works, you should accept so thread is closed and others know.

Answer (score 1):

why do you have a ready function inside a function which is again called inside a window load function..(i think that is unnecessary if `fadeIn()` is only thing that you are doing) ..and it should work..

calls fadeIn on windows load

```
window.onload = function() {
   $('#about').fadeIn('slow'); //fades in the text
};
```

or

calls fade in on document ready

```
$(function() {
    $('#about').fadeIn('slow'); //fades in the text
});
```

Comment: no... it should work fine... because the dom ready handler will call the callback even after the actual dom ready event - see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NE42S/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny i agree but why call `window.onload` + `document.ready` functions just to fade in ..don't you think that is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help... try it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").fadeOut()
  });
  $(".btn2").click(function(){
    $("p").fadeIn();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button class="btn1">Fade out</button>
<button class="btn2">Fade in</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `document.ready` (or `$(function() { ... });`) you don't need to use `window.onload` because the `load` event occurs later than `document.ready` one (say when all images loaded etc.) and you can't catch `document.ready` in this way since you've created a handler after the `ready` event occurred.

So that your options are to use just `document.ready`:

```
function fadingIn() {
    //jQuery
    $(function() {
        $('#about').fadeIn('slow'); //fades in the text
    });
}
fadingIn();
```

or to use just `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = function() {
    fadingIn();
};

function fadingIn() {
    //jQuery
    $('#about').fadeIn('slow'); //fades in the text
}
```

Here is an [excerpt from jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) saying the same:

> The .ready() method is generally incompatible with the `<body onload="">` attribute. If load must be used, either do not use .ready() or use jQuery's .load() method to attach load event 
>   handlers to the window or to more specific items, like images.

Comment: I may consider using the document.ready...I just personally prefer the look of window.onload versus document.ready

Comment: You can use either `document.ready` or `window.onload`. But not `document.ready` in `window.onload` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to write `window.onload` function. You can write in side of `Jquery` DOM ready.

```
$(function () {
    $('#about').fadeIn('slow'); //fades in the text
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function fadingIn(){
    $(function() {
        $('#about').fadeIn('slow');
    });
}
function fadingOut(){
    $(function() {
        $('#about').fadeOut('slow');
    });
}
fadingIn();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "about" style="display:none;">
<h2>About Us</h2>
<p>Objective: To teach and use skills in relation to creating games.</p>
<p>Where: CAT 145</p>
<p>When: Monday's at 6:30pm</p>
</div>
<button onclick="fadingIn()">fadingIn</button>
<button onclick="fadingOut()">fadingOut</button>
</body>
</html>
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/d59uH/1/