# Why is display none in the CSS not removed by fadein?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

So I'm trying to get a div to fade in when a scroll threshold has been reached.  It starts off with display: none; in the css for its div id.  When the threshold is hit, fadein does not remove display:none; from the css as I've read it should.

CSS:

```
#SideBanner01{
  display: none;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: 60.4%;
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: .25%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#SideBanner01 img{
  width: 206.25%;
  margin: -30% -15% -8% -140%;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var delay = 500;
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scrollTop > 20) {
    $('#SideBanner01').fadeIn(delay);
  }
  else{
    $('#SideBanner01').hide();
  }
});
```

Inspector after fadein runs:

```
element {
    position: fixed;
}
#SideBanner01 {
    display: none;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: 60.4%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    margin-top: .25%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body {
    color: #000000;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Html:

```
<div style="position: fixed;" id="SideBanner01"><img src="http://survey.unifocus.com/ClientFiles/19500/Bardessono-stone-wheels.jpg"></div>
```

I'm using jquery 1.6 so I believe fadein should work as I'm trying it.  Any idea on what is going on?  I've been able to get "$('#SideBanner01').show(delay);" to work but it flies in from the side but it looks pretty tacky.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see any console errors?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6446209/2654498

Comment: jqery does nothing to .css file or to `<style>` block. It changes `style` attribute of element(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't you mean to do:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var delay = 500;
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 20) {
    $('#SideBanner01').fadeIn(delay);
  }
  else{
    $('#SideBanner01').hide();
  }
});
```

In your code snippet, `scrollTop` is used as a regular variable (not defined).